# Rename [q] to avoid confusion with [q-lang]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Wiki excerpt for tag [q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/q) contains following:

> The Q.js JavaScript promise library. Q catches errors and uses a `then` technique to handle JavaScript callbacks and exceptions. Do *not* use for Angular's $q, use [angular-promise] instead! Also do *not* use for kx System's kdb+/q, use [kdb] or [q-lang] instead! Lastly, this tag should not be used for questions regarding Android 10 - use the [android-10.0] tag instead!

Notice not to use it for questions about kbd+ somewhat works, I guess: at the moment of writing this [there were 10 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bq%5D%20is%3Aq%20kdb) clearly about kbd+ also tagged with [q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/q). (Total number of questions in the tag [q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/q) is near 1400)

But I think to exclude any possible confusion we should simply rename [q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/q) to [q.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/q.js). Could moderators kindly do so?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of misuse of this tag beyond [kbd]. I just retagged one where "q" seems to have been an abbreviation for "question".

Comment: I agree with @Laurel this needs to be disambiguated first. A direct rename is only going to result in many more mistagged questions. At a quick look there are several questions about [django-q] and [qobjects] and [angular] (despite the warning in the tag wiki excerpt) that a rename at this stage is not going to work.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't checked it before, but it seems like we have quite a bit of [strange usage of this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[q]%20is%3aq%20-kdb%20-[kdb]%20-[javascript]%20-[angularjs]%20-q.js%20-promise%20-[promise]%20-[node.js]%20-[angular]). I guess single letter tag is overall is way to inviting not to use it.

Comment: q.js doesn't sound right, q-promises should be fine (am maintainer). Q is also very much _done_ as in "should probably not be used in any new code and will get no new releases except for vulnerabilities"

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I have no knowledge in this field: my suggestion is based solely on tag wiki. Please add your suggestion as an answer for better visibility.

Comment: I agree with Benjamin, q.js doesn't sound right. The library is (or was) just known as "Q", it's none of those dot-jay-ess libraries.

Comment: FWIW if you google `q.js` [Quantum JavaScript (Q.js)](https://quantumjavascript.app) is the first result; so `q-promises` seems more apt.

Comment: The description for the "q" tag suggests to use [kdb] or [q-lang] for kx System's kdb+/q, but only [kdb] is possible. [q-lang] is actually an alias for [kdb], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/q-lang/info redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kdb/info.

Answer (score 6):

Posting my comment as answer as requested:

[q.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/q.js) doesn't sound right, the library is called Q. [q-promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/q-promises) should be fine (am maintainer). Q is also very much done as in "should probably not be used in any new code and will get no new releases except for vulnerabilities".